# Получить строку таблицы при клике Jquery

Tags: jquery

Есть некоторая таблица, состоящая из нескольких строк и колонок. В последней колонке для каждой строки есть кликабельная картинка. Необходимо получить индекс той строки где был сделан клик, как это можно сделать ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(".clickableImage").click(function(){
  var row = $(this).closest("tr");
  var index = row.parent().children("tr").index(row);
  console.log(index);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так

```js
$('#table td').on('click',function(){
console.log($(this).parent().index());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
<td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
<td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
<td>4</td>
</tr>
</table>
```